# Using class-validator in service nestjs?

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

class-validate always return length = 0 when I try use it in service.

service

```
export class UserService extends BaseService<UserEntity> {
  private validator
  constructor (
    @Inject('USER_RESPOSITORY')
    private userRespository: typeof UserEntity
  ) {
    super(userRespository)
    this.validator = new Validator()
  }

  async create (user: CreateUserDto): Promise<UserEntity> {

    const error = await this.validator.validate(user)

    if (error.length > 0) {
      throw Error('Invalid criterial!')
    }

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
    user.password = hashedPassword
    
    const rs = await super.create(user)

    return rs
  }

}
```

controller:

```
@Post()
async create (@Body() user) {
    return this.userService.create(user)
}
```

dto:

```
export class CreateUserDto {
  @IsEmail()
  email: string

  @Length(8)
  password: string

  @IsOptional()
  isSuperAdmin: number
}
```

value input: {
"email": "nhathanluu",
"password": "nhathan12"
}

class-validate.validate() return empty array. It fine when I validate in controller

Comment: What does CreateUserDto look like? How are you injecting the validator? What data does the user object contain? The question does not contain enough information IMO.

Comment: I was edit more information.

Answer (score 4):

You are taking a plain JavaScript object and validating it. It's not an instance of `CreateUserDto`. The validator does not know about the decorators which provide the validation metadata. It is just validating a plain JS object. The validator will not find any metadata informing it how to validate it. It will consider it valid.

```
async isValid(user: CreateUserDto): Promise<boolean> {
  const validator = new Validator();
  const errors = await validator.validate(user);

  return errors.length === 0;
}

const isValid = await this.isValid({ email: 'john', password: 'test' });
// ==> returns true
```

In case of your controller it is NestJS which transforms it to an instance of `CreateUserDto` and then performs the validation.

Make sure you are dealing with an instance of `CreateUserDto`. You can use the `class-transformer` package to do so or you can set the `transform` option on NestJS's validation pipe. That way it will convert it to such an instance for you.

```
@Body(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })) user: CreateUserDto
```

In case you are using a global `ValidationPipe` you can also set the transform option there, but of course that impacts all endpoints.